# <html:select> multiple values how to get values into Action form

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts-1

I am having two lists Projects and selected_projects  with

```
<html:select>.
```

How to get data from html form to getter setters of  Action Form of struts 1.3

Answer (score 1):

hey Dont worry Its Easy and i m Sure u will do it..
Firstly u wrap all data in Form tag in HTML and just form tag action use in call Action 
i.e actionname.action.

and in that action have must required getter setter of that data.
u get all data automatically..surprise... ?? yes its Done.

i hope u got it.

Comment: Could you please help with sample example

Comment: <form action="actionname.action" id="sending" method="post">
<input type ="text"  name="hasnen"></form>  just in action class make getter setter of hasnen..u can access value of "hasnen."

Comment: Thanks I need to have multiple values selected in html:Select tag on action Class